# Changing variable of this double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This one is fairly a much simpler question compared to my previous one. So the question is $$\int \ \int _R^{ }\ \frac{y}{x}dA$$ where R is bounded by $1\le \ x^2+2y^2\le \ 4$ and $2x\le \ y\le \ 5x$. Given this information we are asked to convert from xy-plane to uv-plane, from the 2nd inequality we can deduce that $2\le \ v\le \ 5$ where $v=\frac{y}{x}$, and now I'm stuck with the expression of $u$ which I'm struggling to form, because when I tried it, it went like this: let $$u= x^2 +2y^2 $$ $$u=x^2(1+ v^2)$$ so I'm still stuck with that $x^2$ that I don't know what to do with, I only need help with the limits and that too with only the 1st inequality. I'll be able to evaluate the integral on my own after that. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u = x^2 + 2y^2\\
v = \frac {y}{x}$

The Jacobean

$du\ dv = \left|\begin{array} {}
\frac {du}{dx} & \frac {dv}{dx}\\
\frac {du}{dy} & \frac {dv}{dy}\end{array}\right|\ dx\ dy$

$du\ dv = \left|\begin{array}{} 
2x & -\frac {y}{x^2}\\
4y & \frac {1}{x}\end{array}\right|\ dx\ dy = (2 + 4\frac {y^2}{x^2})\ dx\ dy\\
\frac {du\ dv}{2+4v^2} = dx\ dy$

$\int_1^4\int_2^5 \frac {v}{2+4v^2}\ dv\ du$

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest a different substitution, with $x=2\rho\cos t,\,y=\sqrt{2}\rho\sin t$ the integral could be written as$$2\int_{1/2}^1\rho d\rho\int_{\arctan(2\sqrt{2})}^{\arctan(5\sqrt{2})}\tan t dt=\frac38\ln\frac{17}{3},$$in agreement with @DougM's result.